# creating professional responsive page

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser

what is the process and what are the best practices for creating modern, responsive pages compatible with all currently used browsers? i've seen csses that have more than 250kb so i don't believe they are written from scratch by hand. do you use some generators or page builders? so how does it actually look like?
how to easily make it portabe? for example rounding radius etc?
starting with creating html markup? then adding css libraries? what libraries? anything for resetting css? sass? or maybe js libraries? when to add @media? do you write it for mobile resolution firsts? or do you write it top down, testing all resolutions after adding every element? what about still widely used IE8?

can anyone plz describe full production process of creating professional responsive cross-browser web pages?

Comment: Your question has a lot of components to it. I would read up a little more and try to ask more specific questions. There are a lot of articles and tutorials already written on this topic. Smashing Magazine has a good guide to start out http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/. I would also look into frameworks like bootstrap and foundation. I don't think it is necessary to rewrite the wheel for make responsive columns.

Comment: true. there's a lot of questions. but the problem with starting with completely new technology is lack of the road. i've read about foundation, bootstrap, sass, seen some tutorials on RWD but every tutorial is showing only one small step without putting it in order. that's why it's good to know how the whole process looks like from the very high perspective

Comment: Start with a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation that will tend to dictate what other tools/approaches you'll use (i.e., SASS/SCSS or LESS).  Bootstrap 3.x still supports IE8, but 4.x is rumored to be dropping support for 8.  Personally, I don't see it being widely used (less than 1%) today by my site visitors, but I suppose that could vary depending on geography, and demographics such as age and consumer audience versus corporate.  There are too many variables to say that there is only one production process or even best practice.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of libraries, but as you say, you'll easily bulk up on a lot of extra stuff you might not need.

Personally I code for a full desktop width and size my browser down, tweaking my code as I go.

When I first looked up how to do RWD, this article was all I needed to get started - http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps

I prefer to write from scratch, rather than use existing libraries, but everyone has their own preference. I like being in complete control of my code so I know where everything is and what it does.

RWD is definitely an art and it takes time to get really good at it.

All said, please keep in mind, Stack Overflow is meant for helping with coding problems. Your question is quite subjective and opinion-based.